# Боковое меню закрывается при нажатии

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Мое боковое меню в мобильной версии сайта закрывается при нажатии, а у меня в нем input с type='range' и выпадающие списки. Как мне сделать так, чтоб оно не закрывалось при нажатии?

```
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import { Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import { debounce } from 'chart.js/helpers';
const SidebarMenu = ({ providers }) => {

return (
  <div>
 <Disclosure>
  <Disclosure.Button 
    className="absolute right-4 inline-flex items-center peer justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white lg:hidden">
    <GiHamburgerMenu
      className="block h-6 w-6"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
  </Disclosure.Button>
    <div className="p-6 w-1/2 h-screen bg-white z-20 fixed -left-60 lg:left-0 lg:w-60 peer-focus:left-0 peer:transition ease-out delay-150 duration-200">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-start item-center">
```